# Trouble installing numpy for Python 3.3 on OSX 10.8

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, homebrew

I had a working Python 3.2 system with Numpy, but I let Homebrew upgrade to Python 3.3, so I have to install all packages again. This fails for `pip3 install numpy` with [this very large output](https://gist.github.com/4488386).

Can you suggest a fix?

Alternatively, how can I get my old working installation back?

Comment: The endian.h not found sounds weird, are you sure you have all the requirements/paths set correctly? In any case I am not certain you can run 1.6. with python 3.3, you may want to try the (or wait a bit) 1.7. release candidate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I successfully installed Numpy under Python3.3 without `pip`:

```
git clone https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

The other option, though not the preferred one, was a Python downgrade via Homebrew. You can switch back and forth with:

```
brew switch python3 <version>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade a formula the old versions are not deleted. You'll find the old version in:
`/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2/`

I think that if you unlink with `brew unlink python3` and the remove the 3.3 folder and link again with `brew unlink python3` you'll get back python 3.2

I have tested for simple formulas like youtube-dl and it works.

Comment: I managed to downgrade to Python3.2 with `brew switch python3 3.2.3`. You can switch back and forth between versions with this command. However, I'd prefer to get Numpy working with Python 3.3.